# Resampling the signal array in Python to use signal.fftconvolve()

Tags: python, fft, convolution

I have a problem with two signals in an array that i want to use with the function `fftconvolve`. 
They represent two measurements of same time duration and the start and the end of the signal are matched.
The trouble is that because of their different sampling rate, at which each measurement was taken, the array lengths are different

```
LS1= len(SIG1) # - > LS1=819
LS2= len(SIG2) # - > LS2=3441
```

therefore the convolution is not calculated properly.

What i need is basically a way to correctly down-sample the longer array signal to get LS1=LS2.

I have tried using it with `mode='same'` as it says in the [function description](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html)

```
 KOR=signal.fftconvolve(SIG1, SIG2, mode='same')
```

but the output still seems strange and I realy dont know if the calculation is correct.

[Here is an example of signal convolution plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XoCn.png)

Than you for any help.

SOLUTION: It was quick & simple! Thank you J. Piquard!! The 'resample' function  does the trick

`SIG2 = signal.resample(SIG2, LS1)`

Comment: Have you tried the [scipy.signal.resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) function ?

Comment: Thank you very much it works excellent! I don't know how i missed this 'resample' function :-/ . I tought I goggled the whole WWW :)

Comment: before Google/WWW, I have spent a lot of time to create my own re-sample algorithm using [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)...

Comment: Thank you for the background source. The programmers life is much more simple these days :) I would probably avoid such project - unless my life was on stake..